# Inserting formula in excel cell with VBA gone wrong?

Tags: vba, excel, formula

It seems that the formula I'm trying to insert using VBA isn't inserted correctly:

```
Range("H3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(MIBIE!D:D,MATCH(A3,MIBIE!A:A,0))"
```

What I end up with in my cell is this:

```
=INDEX(MIBIE!D:(D);MATCH('A3';MIBIE!A:(A);0))
```

Which of course doesn't work, but what I'd need is the following:

```
=INDEX(MIBIE!D:D;MATCH(A3;MIBIE!A:A;0))
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I'm unfortunately unable to use cell reference using C[#] and R[#] as I have many cells I want to edit and it is unable to use columns and rows as a reference, but only the letters of those.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this line instead:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDEX(MIBIE!D:D,MATCH(A3,MIBIE!A:A,0))"
```

If you wanted to set the `FormulaR1C1` then you'd have to write something like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(MIBIE!C[3],MATCH(R[2]C,MIBIE!C,0))"
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, you just made my day :)